# Detect Which Files Changed with Dropbox Sync API

Tags: dropbox-api

I am detecting file changes via the Dropbox Sync API (iOS) like this:

```
[[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] addObserver:self forPathAndDescendants:[DBPath root] block:^() {
    NSLog(@"File(s) changed!");
}];
```

This is all fine and good, but I need to know **which** files changed. How can I make this block return the filenames of the changed files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any support for this, but we've definitely heard this feature request before.

Comment: You're right. It looks like the functionality I need is only available with a `delta` call in the Dropbox Core API.